# (Python Beginner) Code is only working for the last line in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

When I apply this code to a dictionary the loop only works for the last list of names in the dictionary, the loop will not work for the first or second set of names...

```
def function(dictionary, name): 
    for i in dictionary:
        if name == dictionary[i][0]:
            result = "the first name is "+str(dictionary[i][0])+" the second name is "+dictionary[i][1]
        else:
            result = "False"
    print(result)
input("name")
function(dict, name)
```

I assume its an issue with the line 3 but I can not figure it out.
The dictionary would look something like this:

```
dict = {1: ['john','george'], 2: ['tim','eric'], 3: ['josh','logan']}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what you are trying to do please

Comment: Are you trying to check if the 'name' given by the user is in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to iterate (loop) through a dictionary:

```
for keys, vals in your_dct.items():
    if name == vals[0]
      #your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the value of result each time through the loop. In your code you were only printing the value of result the last time through the loop. Hence the code only worked on the last element of the dictionary.

```
def function(dictionary, name): 
    for i in dictionary:
        if name == dictionary[i][0]:
            result = "the first name is "+str(dictionary[i][0])+" the second name is "+dictionary[i][1]
            print(result)
        else:
            result = "False"
            print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some errors , I have fix them here is your working code :

```
dict1 = {1: ['john','george'], 2: ['tim','eric'], 3: ['josh','logan']}


def function(dictionary1, name):
    for key1,value1 in dictionary1.items():
        if name in value1:

            result = "the first name is "+value1[0]+" the second name is "+value1[1]
            return result

    return False

print(function(dict1, input("name")))
```

First thing , since your values in dict are list so  Use `in` operator to check if first name in values or not , instead of `==`

Second thing  , use  `for key,value in dict.items():`  instead of indexing

The third thing you are using `else return` in the same flow so if you search 'josh' it will first return two false and then 'logan' so use return outside of for loop in your code.